# "this" keyword causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, this

I have a `std::map` where I save a pointer to a class. In the constructor of the class several values are passed, so that variables in the class have an actual value. My problem here is that the keyword `this` creates a segmentation fault when I call a  function of that class which uses one of the previously defined variables. This looks like this in detail (short version):

```
Command::Command(const char *name, commandHandler h) // commandHandler is a function pointer
{ 
    this->name = name;
    this->handler = h;
}

Command::execute(int cn, std::vector<char *> args)
{
    if (this->handler != NULL) // "this" is according to gdb a pointer to a class Command at 0x0
        (handler)(cn, args);
}
```

The map is in a static class, the map elements are inserted in a static function.

Edit: Due to the comments and answers (thanks guys):
I add the pointer to the class in a function registerCommands() which basically creates pointers using `Command *command_xxx = new Command("xxx", &(handler_func));` and puts that in a map in a static class. The call comes from another method in the same class as the map and the registerCommands() function. The class pointer is obtained using `commands.find("xxx")->second;` which returns null -> null pointer.

Comment: show the calling code

Comment: Based on the context, the exact problem can't be determined. Based on the description the object on which you want to call the function is lost or you provide a funny pointer (e.g. a null pointer) when calling the member function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The class pointer is obtained using `commands.find("xxx")->second`; which returns null -> null pointer.

And then when you do `commands.find("xxx")->second->execute(...)` you get a segfault. There are (at least) two things wrong here.

One is the `->execute(...)` without checking whether the found item is non-null. You are invoking undefined behavior if the found item is null. What happens with most systems depends on whether or not `execute()` is a virtual function. If it's virtual, you are going to get a segfault or bus error before the call. If it's non-virtual, the underlying machinery knows exactly which function to call. The segfault will occur inside the `execute()` function when you try to access a data member. You should either *know* that a pointer is not null or check whether it is before dispatching an object call. Once you do `->execute()` it's game over, one way or the other.

The other problem is the `->second`. What if `"xxx"` is not in the map? If it isn't, `commands.find("xxx")` will return `commands.end()`, and operating on that is undefined behavior. All you should do with the end iterator is test that you haven't hit it.

It's a bit more verbose, but you should test for those corner cases. You should test even if after painstaking analysis you know with 100% confidence that your `find` will always return an in-bounds iterator and that every in-bounds iterator has a non-null mapped value. You might test via asserts, and you can eventually turn those off, but you should always test. Always.

Comment: Seems like it doesn't saves the class pointer in the map. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This mostly happens when you call a method on a pointer which is set to `NULL`. Since `this` is an hidden parameter that is passed to every member function, GDB shows it as `NULL`. Eg:

```
Command *command = NULL;
command->execute(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a pointer to a `Command` somewhere, but the pointer is `0`. This pointer is then used to call `Command::execute`, which means the member function is called with `this == 0`.

While it is not standard conforming, you can most likely try to add code to catch this and print some information that might help to debug the problem:

```
if(!this) print_backtrace();
```

or something similar. (For a backtrace on Linux, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190273/how-to-print-call-stack-in-c-c-more-beautifully/19190421#19190421) I gave shortly ago)